# Change Environment Variables Saved In .env File With Python and dotenv

Tags: python, environment-variables, dotenv

I am trying to update .env environment variables with python. With `os.environ` I am able to view and change local environment variables, but I want to change the .env file. Using `python-dotenv` I can load .env entries into local environment variables

.env File

```
key=value
```

test.py

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

print(os.environ['key']) # outputs 'value'

os.environ['key'] = "newvalue"

print(os.environ['key']) # outputs 'newvalue'
```

.env File

```
key=value
```

The .env File is not changed! Only the local env variable is changed. I could not find any documentation on how to update the .env file. Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: You will need to write to the `.env`. Your code does not do that.

Comment: @jakub what do you mean?

Comment: See the `dotenv.set_key` method https://saurabh-kumar.com/python-dotenv/reference/dotenv/#set_key

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Use [`dotenv.set_key`](https://saurabh-kumar.com/python-dotenv/reference/#dotenv.set_key).

```
import dotenv

dotenv_file = dotenv.find_dotenv()
dotenv.load_dotenv(dotenv_file)

print(os.environ["key"])  # outputs "value"
os.environ["key"] = "newvalue"
print(os.environ['key'])  # outputs 'newvalue'

# Write changes to .env file.
dotenv.set_key(dotenv_file, "key", os.environ["key"])
```

Comment: dotenv.find_dotenv() is what i need. Thank you.