# How to set environment variables in a local .env file using dotenv in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables, dotenv

I tried the following code but when I opened my env file it was still empty.

```py
import os
from os.path import join, dirname
from dotenv import load_dotenv
    
dotenv_path = join(dirname(__file__), '.env')
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)
    
os.environ['ORI'] = '123'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `dotenv.set_key` for that, like this:

```py
import dotenv

dotenv_path = "my-custom-dotenv"

# dotenv.set_key will create a dotenv file
# with the specified path if non existing, then add the "ORI" variable
dotenv.set_key(dotenv_path, "ORI", "123")
# add the IRO variable
dotenv.set_key(dotenv_path, "IRO", "321")
# change the ORI variable
dotenv.set_key(dotenv_path, "ORI", "456")
# remove the IRO variable
dotenv.unset_key(dotenv_path, "IRO")
```

Comment: Thanks, It worked but can you tell me how do I change the name of the env file it creates and how do I delete keys from the file?

Comment: @RosoBergman you mean that you don't want to call it `.env` but something like `.my-custom-dotenv` ?

Comment: Yea but don't mind it I found how to do it by playing a bit with the code, thanks for the help

Comment: In any case I've updated the answer with a possible approach

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv

You first create your `.env` file and write your various variables. For example a `.env` might look like:

```
password=SUPERSECRETPASSWORD
username=myusername
```

and so forth. Then you will load your `.env` using the `load_dotenv()` function.

This is an example from some code I have in a project:

```
import os
import psycopg2 as pg2
from dotenv import load_dotenv

# -------------------------------
# Connection variables
# -------------------------------
dotenv_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', '.env')) #travels up a level to find the .env
load_dotenv(dotenv_path)

# -------------------------------
# Connection to database
# -------------------------------
# Server connection
db_url = os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL")
CONN = pg2.connect(db_url, sslmode="require")
```

**Please make sure you add `.env` to your `.gitignore` file!!!!**

EDIT: NVM I misread the question. I'll leave it in though.

Comment: The question is about setting not loading.

Comment: The thing is that I want the env file to start as an empty file and I want in the code to add variables to the file, I tried your and added os.environ['ORI'] = '123', but still when I opened my .env file in notepad it was empty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63837315/change-environment-variables-saved-in-env-file-with-python-and-dotenv sorry for misreading the question

Comment: @RosoBergman Look at my answer for a possible solution for your problem.